# How to use JavaScript to set the color of the following Color Picker? (By targeting the input element via console?)

Tags: javascript, color-picker

This is the color picker (It's called Spectrum):

http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/

[image]

I want to use JavaScript to add, say `#000000` to the input element (via console).

`<input class="sp-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">`

I tried this in the console (Chrome):

```
var inputEl = document.querySelector('.sp-input')
inputEl.value = '#000000'
```

However, the console just outputs `"#000000"` and the input in the color picker never changes.

How to add values to this input field with JavaScript?

**Note**: This is another website and I didn't initialize the jQuery element, so I don't know which one is the original element.

Comment: Should just be `document.querySelector('.sp-input')` (No period at the end)

Comment: @FrankerZ Thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: So you want us to read these docs for you? There is a set method, so $el.spectrum('set', value)

Comment: The docs for Spectrum indicate you can initialize it with a "color" property, or you can put the color in the "value" of the input.

Comment: @Kaiido `var el = document.querySelector('.sp-input'); el.spectrum('set', '#000000')` throws `VM129:1 Uncaught TypeError: el.spectrum is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:4`

Comment: @bcr666 Sorry, I didn't specify. I want to add the color to the input value via Chrome console and JavaScript.

Comment: **$** el... This is a jquery plugin

Comment: @Kaiido this is another website so I don't know which one is the original spectrum element.

Comment: It is always the hidden input just before the `<div .sp-replacer>`.